# Code for running a different workbook from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a question, My question is that I have two workbooks let's say book1 and book2, so I have a macro in the book1, and I want to execute and perform the task in the book2 but the macro is in the book1, please I need help with a code of doing such

i try
`Application.run "'workbook1.xlsm", !macro1'"`, but still it's running in the workbook where the code is created

Comment: Does your code use `ActiveWorkbook` and `ActiveSheet`, either implicitly or explicitly?

Comment: Well-covered here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win001.htm   Probably a good idea to share the code for the macro you're running.

Comment: no sir the code those not contain such

Comment: We can't help without your code.

Comment: ohk ill send the code here

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that both workbooks are open. Then, in the workbook containing the macro (book1), you can use the following code to run a macro in the other workbook (book2):

```
Sub RunMacroInAnotherWorkbook()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    
    ' Check if the target workbook (book2) is open
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wb = Workbooks("book2.xlsx") ' Change the filename if needed
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ' If the target workbook is open, run the macro
    If Not wb Is Nothing Then
        wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate ' Activate a specific sheet if needed
        Application.Run "'" & wb.Name & "'!MacroName" ' Change MacroName to the actual macro name
    Else
        MsgBox "The target workbook is not open.", vbExclamation
    End If
End Sub
```

Replace "book2.xlsx" with the actual name of your second workbook, and "MacroName" with the name of the macro you want to run. Also, adjust the sheet name and other details as needed.

Make sure that you've enabled macros in both workbooks and granted necessary permissions for them to run.

Comment: thanks Indeed for your support, but unfortunately, the code is still running in the same file that the code was created

Comment: That is because your code is referencing that workbook. Please, upload your main code so we can help you.

Comment: Here is the code                                                                                                                                     Sub rename_shape()
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
 Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
shp.Name = "sheet1"
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("TD Diagram").Activate
With ActiveChart.ChartArea.format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
    .Name = "Times New Roman"
    .Size = 8
    .Bold = msoTrue
End With
Next
End Sub